# Comparison of symbols containing normal numbers and superscript numbers in SQL Server

Tags: sql, unicode, collation, superscript

I am just running into some problems on SQL Server while comparing columns that contain superscript characters beside standard characters. As long as I compare the columns in VARCHAR, it works as expected. In NVARCHAR normal numbers and superscript numbers are treated as equal as demonstrated in the following sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE #uom
(
    SYMBOL_N1 NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
,   SYMBOL_N2 NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
,   SYMBOL_V1 VARCHAR(50)  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
,   SYMBOL_V2 VARCHAR(50)  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
)

INSERT INTO #uom VALUES ('in²','in2','in²','in2')

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN SYMBOL_N1 = SYMBOL_N2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS N
,   CASE WHEN SYMBOL_V1 = SYMBOL_V2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS V
FROM #uom;

--RESULTS
--N = 1
--V = 0
```

As we also use international characters in some cases, UNICODE must be used here.

Anyone has an idea, how to make SQL Server to treat both values as different?

Best, Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use binary collate

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN SYMBOL_N1 COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN  = SYMBOL_N2 COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS N
,   CASE WHEN SYMBOL_V1 = SYMBOL_V2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS V
FROM #uom;
```

Comment: pay attention that this method does a binary match between strings so you could have problems with accents or case sensitive